# Where can I see how many comments a user wrote on Reddit?

Tags: reddit

I'm looking for a program or webservice to see where can I see how many comments a user wrote on Reddit.

https://redditsearch.io/  doesn't seem to have the option anymore to view how many comments a user wrote on Reddit:

[image]

Any OS, any license, any price is fine. CLI or GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Redective](https://www.redective.com/) + a fairly simple script (whether JS ran in browser dev tools or scraper code) to sum all the cell values on all pages looks like the best solution.